# CruiseControlException when connecting to source control

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I'm getting an exception from Cruise Control about not being able to connect to the server. However, if I force a build it works just fine. I've also tried using the repo-browser to connect to the server without any problems so I know that the server is up and running. I'm running CCNET 1.4.4 and SlikSVN 1.5.3. Below is the exception from the CCNET log:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException:
Source control operation failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://some-server.com/trunk': could not connect to server (https://some-server.com) .
Process command: C:\Program\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe log https://some-server.com/trunk -r "{2009-06-23T01:36:19Z}:{2009-06-23T07:20:25Z}" --verbose --xml --username ccnet --password auto --non-interactive --no-auth-cache
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo) 
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.MultiSourceControl.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to) vid ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well it gives you the command there. " C:\Program\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe log https://some-server.com/trunk -r "{2009-06-23T01:36:19Z}:{2009-06-23T07:20:25Z}" --verbose --xml --username ccnet --password auto --non-interactive --no-auth-cache" I'd try typing that into a command prompt and see if you get a more helpful error message.

Comment: I have done that as well and it does not give me any errors at all. Everything works just fine.

Comment: @Kristoffer -> when you ran it from the command line did you use the same svn user you have configured? I just find it hard to believe that it does not connect if you can connect on the command line. If everything is equal success by hand should mean success in CC. There is no magic in there...

Comment: @Alex -> Yes, I did use the same user. And I agree that it should work but for some reason it didn't. Now I have upgraded to SlikSVN 1.6.3 and so far I'm not getting any errors. I'll post a note here when I know it's working properly.

Comment: Why are you using 'SlikSVN'? Why not stock CollabNet binaries? Also, with HTTPS transport, the first thing to usually suspect are wrong/missing server certificates.

Comment: @Skolima -> SlikSVN was used because it was already installed on our build server. In regards to HTTPS I know that has been the root of some problems we've had before but I know that is not the case here. Thanks for the input though. I'll have a look at CollabNet!

Comment: Update: Still failing! But now it gives me the following message (translated from Swedish):

SSL negotiation failed: An existing connection was forced to shut down the remote host.

Comment: Update 2: Still failing! But this time the exception is back to the original one.

Comment: I am getting this error using the CollabNet SVN - latest version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working again and this is what I've done.

- Set maxSourceControlRetries to 10 in my CCNET-config
- Set sourceControlErrorHandling to ReportOnEveryRetryAmount in my CCNET-config
- Switched to the latest version of CollabNet client

As it turns out, CCNET swallowed sourcecontrol-errors like this in previous versions so I might have had troubles even before I updated to CCNET 1.4.4 but was unaware of it.

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem, but not sure really how to fix it. After the changes that you have done, are you not getting the exception anymore at all or is it actually forcebuilding everyime you get the exception?

Comment: I might still be getting the error but not more the 10 times in a row as I am not receiving any error reports from CruiseControl any more. The build seems just fine now! And no, I am not forcing the build every time.

Comment: I have the same problem. I did the first two things long time ago, and I know it reduces the 'frequency', but it does not solve the actual *problem*. I think it has something to do with not being able to resolve the host name, or no network connection. We see it happen usually at night, so some server may 'sleep' or whatever and it can't connect. Anyway, it's an annoying problem and I can't seem to fix it completely :(

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem when changing the SVN source near a code freeze.  I create a release tag, and change the source control section to refer to the tag and not the development branch.  However, the build working directory will still contain the source for the development branch, including all the SVN metafiles. This triggers the exception due to collision of SVN sources (the original dev branch and the new release tag).

In this case, **the simple solution is to delete the code (directories and all) from the build working directory**, and let CruiseControl pull source for the development branch from the new location.

Here is an excerpt from a ccnet.config file that has been modified to cause this problem.  Does it look familiar?

```
<sourcecontrol type="multi">
    <sourceControls>
        <svn>
            <!--
            <trunkUrl>https://svn/Engineering/Applications/Quasar/branches/TeamRowdy</trunkUrl>
            -->
            <trunkUrl>https://svn/Engineering/Applications/Quasar/tags/REL-TeamRowdy-RC1-2013.07.17.003</trunkUrl>
            <workingDirectory>Quasar</workingDirectory>
            <cleanUp>true</cleanUp>
            <forceUpdate>true</forceUpdate>
        </svn>
        <svn>
            <!--
            <trunkUrl>https://svn/Engineering/Applications/Acme/branches/TeamRowdy</trunkUrl>
            -->
            <trunkUrl>https://svn/Engineering/Applications/Acme/tags/REL-TeamRowdy-RC1-2013.07.17.003</trunkUrl>
            <workingDirectory>Acme</workingDirectory>
            <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
        </svn>
    </sourceControls>
</sourcecontrol>
```